# Can I delete the snapshots and AMI in zone zone after successfully copying the AMI to another zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I have created an AMI in one Asian zone, ap-southeast-1.
The related snapshot is saved and of course cannot be deleted.

I then copied this AMI to eu-west-1.

Can I somehow get rid of the ap snapshots and AMI?
I noticed that the snapshot is also copied in the destination zone so it should be ok but I can't find any doc on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  You need to first deregister the AMI, then you can delete the Snapshot.

> Note that you can't delete a snapshot of the root device of an EBS volume used by a registered AMI. You must first deregister the AMI before you can delete the snapshot.

[Deleting an Amazon EBS Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-deleting-snapshot.html)